# Android - исключение java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! В приложении пишу класс с "утилитами", вот код:

---

```
class Utilities
{
Context ctx;
public Utilities (Context c) {
    this.ctx = c;
}

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
SharedPreferences shpf = ctx.getSharedPreferences("GBreak_ShPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor shpfed = shpf.edit();

public int getDisplayWidth() {
    return display.getWidth();
}

public int getDisplayHeight() {
    return display.getHeight();
}

public void loge(String message) {
    Log.e("gbreak", message);
}

public int getInt(String name) {
    return shpf.getInt(name, 0);
}

public float getFloat(String name) {
    return shpf.getFloat(name, 0f);
}

public long getLong(String name) {
    return shpf.getLong(name, 0);
}

public String getString(String name) {
    return shpf.getString(name, "");
}

public boolean getBoolean(String name) {
    return shpf.getBoolean(name, false);
}

public void writeInt(String name, int ValueToWrite) {
    shpfed.putInt(name, ValueToWrite);
    shpfed.commit();
}

public void writeFloat(String name, float ValueToWrite) {
    shpfed.putFloat(name, ValueToWrite);
    shpfed.commit();
}

public void writeLong(String name, long ValueToWrite) {
    shpfed.putLong(name, ValueToWrite);
    shpfed.commit();
}

public void writeString(String name, String ValueToWrite) {
    shpfed.putString(name, ValueToWrite);
    shpfed.commit();
}

public void writeBoolean(String name, boolean ValueToWrite) {
    shpfed.putBoolean(name, ValueToWrite);
    shpfed.commit();
}
```

}

---

Создаю экземпляр класса в MainActivity в onCreate:

---

```
Utilities utils = new Utilities(this);
```

---

При запуске приложения выкидывает NPE, который указывает на строку

---

```
public Utilities(Context c) {
```

---

Вроде бы все переменные определены. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуй передавать не this, а getApplicationContext() (вроде так, если я не ошибаюсь)

Comment: Попробовал. Не помогло. Продолжает ругаться на ту же стоку.

Comment: Перенесите инициализацию полей в конструктор

Comment: Пробовал. Всё так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ого вот же у вас ошибка! все верно, нулевой указатель

```
class Utilities
{
Context ctx;//сначала выполнится эта строчка
public Utilities (Context c) {
    this.ctx = c;
}
//ниже код выполнится до public Utilities (Context c), но сразу после Context ctx;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);//тут ctx==null
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    SharedPreferences shpf = ctx.getSharedPreferences("GBreak_ShPref", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor shpfed = shpf.edit();
//-----------------------------------//вот теперь запустится конструктор Utilities ()

public int getDisplayWidth() {
    return display.getWidth();
}
}
```

---

---

---

код ниже работает?

```
class Utilities
{
Context ctx=null;
WindowManager wm = null;
Display display = null;
SharedPreferences shpf = null;
Editor shpfed = null;

public Utilities (Context c) {
    this.ctx = c;

    //все переменные уже созданы и под них выделена память, мы её инициализируем и читаем
    wm = (WindowManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    shpf = ctx.getSharedPreferences("GBreak_ShPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    shpfed = shpf.edit();
}
}
```

p.s. до конструктора переменные можно инициализировать только константами или null\0\"", всё остальное делать или в конструкторе или в myOnCreate().

Comment: Я уже сам решил проблему. Унаследовал класс от Activity, теперь у него есть собственный Context. После конструктора просто ввёл названия переменных, а в onCreate определил их. Кстати, ваш код тоже сработал!

Comment: ну логично, ошибка то была в том что вы используете переменную до её инициализации, а не в наличии передаваемого контекста.